# Inserting a new line feed within a character array

Tags: c++

I want to insert a new line feed within an array such that if the string length of my array increases beyond say 14 here the further contents of the array when displayed are displayed in a new line in the output console. Foe e.g Here in below program I want to Display "mein hoon don" in first line and after these 14 characters. I want to DISPLAY next content "Don Don Don" in a new line in output console. I read that using \0xa(hexa) and \10 in decimal are newline feed . But When i tried to use them in my code , I was not able to produce desired output.

```
# include <iostream.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char abc[40];
    strcpy(abc,"mein hoon don.");
    abc[15]='\10';
    abc[16]='\0';
    strcat(abc,"Don Don Don");
    cout << "value of abc is " << abc;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: yeah you can say that ..as i have also never done that before but thats a requirement for me :(

Comment: \0 will effectively terminate you string as it's a null terminator. try abc[15] = '\r'; abc[16] = '\n';  There are much better ways of doing thins, for example with stringstream... Oh, and if you need hex values you need to write something like: abc[15] = '\x0a';

Comment: The only thing is i need to make sure that after the 15 or 14 or whatever a certain number of characters . The rest character in that array should be automatically take a new line while displaying in Output console

Comment: @Yaniro What i have done is that i have used \0 in above code to concatenate the second part Don Don Don in array after "mein hoon don."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
abc[15] = '\10';
abc[16] = '\0';
```

to:

```
abc[14] = '\n';
abc[15] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks man .. i am sorry i caused inconvenince due to wrong index calculation .

Answer (score 2):

The escape sequence `\10` does not do what you think it does.  It is probably easiest to use `\n` instead.

*Note:* you could also use `strcat` to insert the newline and prevent any index calculation problems:

```
strcpy(abc,"mein hoon don.");
/* abc[15]='\10'; */
/* abc[16]='\0'; */
strcat(abc, "\n");
strcat(abc,"Don Don Don");
```

You are really better off using `std::string` instead of `char` arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string s;
    s = "mein hoon don.";
    s += "\n";
    s += "Don Don Don";
    std::cout << value of abc is " << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: using a \n as in abc[15]='\n' does not  meet my requirement

Comment: Why not? it doesn't work or are you required to use something else?

Comment: In that case value are displayed in console as "mein hoon don.Don Don Don" and i dont want that

Comment: you can try run the same programe and replace \10 or \a with \n . What you would see they getting Displayed in same line in Output console

Comment: @Ritesh, The array index is off by one (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the escape secuence depends on the operating system you are working: there are two caracters \r (carrier return) and \n (line feed), in windows, you need both, in linux, you need only \r and in Mac, you need \n.

but, as long as you are using cpp, you shouldnt use any of them, you should use endln instead:

```
//# include <stdio.h>
//# include <stdlib.h>
//# include <string.h>

#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //char abc[40];
    std::ostringstream auxStr;

    auxStr << "mein hoon don." << std::endl << "Don Don Don" << std::endl;

    //if you need a string, then:
    //std::string abc = auxStr.str();

    std::cout << "value of abc is " << auxStr.str();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: thanks Hiperion for your suggestion ...but i needed to pass this character array to a function whose parameter type is char* . In my actual code i have put them in char* abc and allocated size by new .

Comment: Well, then, you only need do:

strncpy (abc, auxStr.str().c_str(), 39);
abc[40] = 0;

Answer (score 0):

This code introduces a line break condition at position x.

Just set `Line_Break=14;`  and you are done.

```
# include <iostream.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int LinePos=0; 
    int Line_Break_Pos=0;
    int Line_Break=10;
    char abc[40]={""};

    strcpy(abc,"mein hoon don. ");
    strcat(abc,"Don Don Don");

    cout << "\n" ;
    cout << "Without linebreak : \n";
    cout << abc ;
    cout << "\n\n" ;
    cout << "With linebreak    : \n" ;


     while (LinePos < strlen(abc) )
     {
         cout <<abc[LinePos];
         if (Line_Break_Pos > Line_Break && abc[LinePos ]==' ')
         {
             cout << "\n" ;
             Line_Break_Pos=0;
         }

         LinePos++;
         Line_Break_Pos++;
     }


    cout << "\n\n" ;
    return 0;
}
```